# Race condition using Flux.merge()

Tags: spring-webflux, race-condition, project-reactor

I'm very new to reactive programming.
My project based on Spring WebFlux.

Here is my merge-method:

```
//fn1 and fn2 are JS functions with one int param, count - I execute them with param from 0 to count.  
public Flux<String> generateUnordered(String fn1, String fn2, int count) {
    Flux<String> fn1Flux = generateFunctionResultFlux(fn1, count, FUNCTION_1)
            .map(fnResult->String.format(UNORDERED_OUTPUT,fnResult[0],fnResult[1],fnResult[2],fnResult[3]));

    Flux<String> fn2Flux = generateFunctionResultFlux(fn2, count, FUNCTION_2)
            .map(fnResult->String.format(UNORDERED_OUTPUT,fnResult[0],fnResult[1],fnResult[2],fnResult[3]));

    return Flux.merge(fn1Flux, fn2Flux)
            .delayElements(Duration.ofMillis(DELAY));
}
```

when I execute it with JS functions as below and count=2

```
function fn1(number) {return number +100;}
function fn2(number) {return number +200;}
```

I get something like that :

> 0,FUNCTION_2,200.0,0

> **0,FUNCTION_1,200.0,0**

But there is clearly seen that I somehow get fn2 result in fn1 row!

What am I doeing wrong and how can I fix it?

GitHub link on project:[WebFlux project](https://github.com/BrSeal/webFlux)

GitHub link on class: [FluxGenerator class](https://github.com/BrSeal/webFlux/blob/master/src/main/java/study/webFlux/controller/FluxGenerator.java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in other part of programm.
To calculate JS functions I used class field ScriptEngine that is **NOT** thread-safe.

Making ScriptEngine local field solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

With merge operator sources are subscribed eagerly. So I guess first flux will emit as soon as subscribed and the second one will be. Because they emit immediately. If you want to see interleaved flux you'll need to delay your emmision.

```
        Flux<Integer> fluxOfIntegers = Flux.merge(
      evenNumbers.delayElements(Duration.ofMillis(500L)), 
      oddNumbers.delayElements(Duration.ofMillis(300L)));
        
    StepVerifier.create(fluxOfIntegers)
      .expectNext(1)
      .expectNext(2)
      .expectNext(3)
      .expectNext(5)
      .expectNext(4)
      .expectComplete()
      .verify();
```

If you want more examples of operators you can check [this](https://www.baeldung.com/reactor-combine-streams#4-merge)